# Beacons created with altbeacon are not detected as beacons

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, ibeacon-android

I am struggling with one Android app using the altbeacon library ([here](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/index.html)). I am using the code provided as an example on their website:

```
Beacon beacon = new Beacon.Builder()
    .setId1("2f234454-cf6d-4a0f-adf2-f4911ba9ffa6")
    .setId2("1")
    .setId3("2")
    .setManufacturer(0x0118)
    .setTxPower(-59)
    .setDataFields(Arrays.asList(new Long[] {0l}))
    .build();
BeaconParser beaconParser = new BeaconParser()
    .setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25");
BeaconTransmitter beaconTransmitter = new 
BeaconTransmitter(getApplicationContext(), beaconParser); 
beaconTransmitter.startAdvertising(beacon);
```

I have created the app that handles correctly the bluetooth adapter, manager, advertiser etc. Bluetooth starts ok, no errors on etc. When the beacon starts I read in logs:

```
D/BluetoothLeAdvertiser: start advertising
D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
D/BluetoothLeAdvertiser: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=10
D/BluetoothLeAdvertiser: onMultiAdvertiseCallback status = 0 isStart = true
I/BeaconTransmitter: Advertisement start succeeded.
I/MonitoringActivityaaa: Beacon started OK
```

It seems that everything works OK but the (virtual) beacons are not visible as beacons. I can see that some BT devices are detected and appear exactly when they should (when the start advertising is triggered) but no beacons detected. When I try other applications that create/advertise virtual beacon - they work correctly. I am testing it on Galaxy S7 with Android 7.0.

Anybody had the same case? Are there any other settings that I should set?

Comment: it turned out that layout and company code needs to be set up correctly. See here for details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46868465/working-ibeacon-ble-beacon-app-code-example. Case solved!