# Working iBeacon/BLE beacon app code example

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, beacon

I am looking for a tested working example code of android app that creates a virtual beacon and starts advertising it. Ive tested already couple of tutorials/examples but without success. My target environment is Android 7 on Galaxy S7.
Appreciate your help.
!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a transmitter section on the Android Beacon Library sample page here:

http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html

Two tips to making this work so it is detectable by another app.

1. Set the proper BeaconLayout of the beacon type you want to transmit.  You can see the beacon layout strings for various beacon types here:

https://beaconlayout.wordpress.com

2. If you want to transmit iBeacon make sure you set the company code to that of Apple (0x004c) so it is recognized as an Apple iBeacon format.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for. I tried different layouts and few days ago started to experiment also with company code (".setManufacturer" field). This does the trick - so in order to have beacon recognized as iBeacon you need both proper layout and company code. Otherwise it will be recognized as peripheral.

Comment: Now I have another challenge. It seems when my phone is connected to handsfree BT in the car there are cases when the beacon advertisement does not stop when i execute '.stopAdvertising()'. I replicated this couple of times - it seems that when phone is connected to bluetooth for longer period of time things like that happen. I need to test it with different bluetooth devices.